# Power BI - "Other" Classfication Based on Percentage of Total

Tags: powerbi

quick question:

I have a total amount that is divided into several classifications, like so:

Total: 7bn

Classification 1: 3bn,

Classification 2: 1bn,

... ,

Classification N: 0,3M

N is such a big number that when I put in a graph, most of the classifications don't even show up in there, so my manager suggested that I took anything that represents less than 5% of the total 7bn and classified them as "Others" to put it all together in the visual.

Then I made a measure "% of total" like:

```
% of total = 
divide( 
    sum(values), 
    sumx(
        allselected(table), 
        values
    )
)
```

And this actually works perfect, except...

I wanna make a measure (or calculated column) that returns something like:

```
new classification = 
if(
    [% of total] > 0.05, 
    "Others", 
    [classification] 
)
```

just to classify for me in the graph

but then only one of the new classifications returns as the old one, the rest returns "Others", but I know there's more than one, according to [% of total].

Can you think of another way to make this work? Is this a dumb question?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 separate measure for [others] & [classification] and create your final measure as below-

```
new classification = 

var is_greater = IF([% of total] > 0.05, 1, 0)

RETURN
SWITCH(
    is_greater , 
    1,[Others]", 
    [classification] 
)
```